# View null pointer exception

Tags: android, view, null

In MyFragmentActivity.java I use the onKeyDown method to detect if the user press the volume up button, then I pass the key to other method in MyFragment class, and here when I call myView.postInvalidate(); I get NPE. What i´m missing?

MyFragment.java code:

```
    public class MyFragment  extends SherlockFragment implements OnTouchListener{

public MyView myView= null;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
            {       

                myView = new MyView(getActivity());
                myView.setOnTouchListener(this);    
                return myView;      
            }



    public void myOnKeyDown(int key_code){    


    if(key_code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){

    myView.postInvalidate();    //myView is null

                }

        }
```

MyFragmentActivity.java code:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


            ((MyFragment) mTabsAdapter.getItem(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                return true;
            }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

The problem is when I call  myView.postInvalidate() outside of MyFragment class, I have no issues calling it directly from MyFragment.

**LOGCAT:**

```
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.My.App.MyFragment.myOnKeyDown(MyFragment.java:398)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.My.App.MyFragmentActivity.onKeyDown(MyFragmentActivity.java:173)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1037)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:122)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 21:48:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Always… _always_ post the log cat whenever you have an error. _Always_. Even if we can guess from the code, I'm not taking the time on something that could be clear as water by looking at the logs.

Comment: Looks like you are calling `myView.postInvalidate()` before it is initialized. Add some logging to show when `myView` is initialized.

Comment: It´s initialized when MyFragment is created, calling myView.postInvalidate(); directly from this class works well, but I need to call it in MyFragmentActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment's `onCreateView` method is calling only when this fragment becomes visible. So i think you call  `((MyFragment) mTabsAdapter.getItem(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);` before fragment is initialized. In any case there is may be state when this event has happened aready but fragment is not initialized yet. So you should check `myView` for null value.

Comment: I call ((MyFragment) mTabsAdapter.getItem(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode); after onCreateView is initialized. Now I have 3 classes: class1 -> class2 -> classView, When I update the classView from class2 I dont have any issue, but when I call the update from class1 I get the null view.